# Erro parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I checked maximum solutions given in website but still i'm not able to find error and solve this problem. Please help me to solve this problem.

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fbuserinfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        facebook:preset_size="small" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/facebook_loading"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the *full* error message? I'd expect it to be more than that...

Comment: Erro parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Eclipse shows me this text only.\

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
android:xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I'd expect it to just be:

```
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: After trying your code this error generated
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag 
  LinearLayout
 - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: @user1308205: Hmm... that's very odd... it's just specifying a namespace URI for the `facebook` alias. I don't have time to help any further now, but I'd check examples *very* carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Change your LinearLayout check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize/),

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
....
```

Comment: There should be no need to redeclare the android namespace alias.